# Can't call function with button click (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a very strange issue. I have a button which currently prints a barcode label using the following code:

```
<button id="printButton">
          PRINT BARCODE LABEL
      </button>
```

This button then successfully calls:

```
printButton.onclick = function()
      { CODE }
```

The problem is that I wish to be able to print multiple barcode labels with a single button press. So, I changed the javascript function to:

```
function print()
      { CODE }
```

And added

```
printButton.onclick = function()
    {
      print();
    }
```

With the idea being that I can ultimately call multiple print functions (print1() print2() etc) from the same button press. The problem is, when I rewrite the code as above, nothing happens, even though it seems to me that the exact same thing should happen as happened before? Any idea? I am happy to post the full code if anyone thinks that might help.

Comment: You don't need to post the full code, but you do need to post enough code to replicate the issue. Do you see errors in the browser's error console?

Comment: seems all is [ok](http://jsfiddle.net/m1yke6sc/)

Comment: thanks for your answers guys. the problem ended up being that the original functions were inside a 'onload' function, I had created the new function outside it.

Answer (score -1):

i would do:

```
 $('#printButton').on('click',function (){
   //call print method
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    var a1 = function (_func) { console.log('print'); if (_func != null) { _func()} }

    printButton.onclick = function () {
        a1(a1(a1(a1(null))));
    }
```

```html
<button id="printButton"> PRINT BARCODE LABEL</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
function print(){alert('print func');}
printButton.onclick =  print;
```

```html
<button id="printButton">
          PRINT BARCODE LABEL
      </button>
```

Comment: OP said: With the idea being that I can ultimately call multiple print functions (print1() print2() etc) from the same button press.

Comment: call them in the print function, do you want 10 alerts coming up ????`function print(){ printfunction1();printfunction2();}`

Comment: still it can not be the cause of the problem. There is no difference between calling multiple functions in anonymous or named function....

Comment: I quote ` The problem is, when I rewrite the code as above, nothing happens, even though it seems to me that the exact same thing should happen as happened before? `, So you decide that the OP has no problem and give a downvote even though OP obviously has a problem which my answer sorts out.

Comment: omg, you can not help with your answer, see my comment to OPs code, i just write his code and it is working. That means that problem is not found. You rewrite his code too and changed 1 thing which does not relate to the question in any way and thinks that this is an answer??

Comment: your comment was after my answer ? my code works and you've only just changed mine slightly, only just noticed you actually had code as you only put it in a fiddle with the ok as a link, your comment above this that says ` i just write his code and it is working. That means that problem is not found` makes absolutely no sense. when you've put your toys back in the pram and stopped using your different accounts to downvote me then maybe the OP ( which I suspect maybe you anyway ) will tell us whether it sorts the problem

Comment: no, my comment was before your answer, it's first. Comments are for clarification a questions, so my comment had hinted OP to give more info about his problem - and this have sense (unlike your answer) - it's second. And finally, stop your paranoia, it's not my question lol and i dont have other accounts to downvote you. If you doing it does not mean that others do so.